When using AndroidRemoteView, AdapterViewFlipper remoteViews does not work
I am currently implementing an AppWidget using Glance. My appwidget needs to implement ViewFlipper for the AppWidget, so I am trying to use AndroidRemoteViews. But in the case of ViewFlipper, it does not work on AndroidRemoteViews.
Is there anyone who knows why the combination of AndroidRemoteViews and ViewFlipper does not work with the code below?
class MyAppWidget : GlanceAppWidget() {
    // In this method, load data needed to render the AppWidget.
    // Use `withContext` to switch to another thread for long running
    // operations.

    override suspend fun provideGlance(context: Context, id: GlanceId) {
        provideContent {
            Box (modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                GlanceViewFlipper()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GlanceViewFlipper() {
    val remoteViews = RemoteViews(LocalContext.current.packageName ?: "", R.layout.adapter_view_flipper)
    val intent = Intent(LocalContext.current, AdapterViewFlipperService::class.java)
    remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.view_flipper, intent)
    AndroidRemoteViews(remoteViews)
}

class GlanceMyAppWidget : GlanceAppWidgetReceiver() {
    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget = MyAppWidget()
}

By the way, the log below is suspicious.
15:51:36.154 25827-25827 RemoteViews   ....  setRemoteAdapter can only be used for AppWidgets (root id: 2131165394)
Try to fix it but need help

After further checking, it was not a problem with the glance, but with the android framework RemoteViews. As a result, it seems that the use of ViewFlipper in glance is impossible.
